# How to test zabbix simple check in command line?

Tags: zabbix

Just like zabbix_get for zabbix agent:

```
/usr/local/zabbix/bin/zabbix_get -s 10.10.10.1 -p10050 -k system.uptime
```

Answer (score 9):

`zabbix_agent -t vm.memory.size[free]`

If you are using Zabbix Agent 2 use:

`zabbix_agent2 -t vm.memory.size[free]`

Comment: Note that this may be `zabbix_agentd -t vm.memory.size[free]` ending with `d` in some distributions like CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Simple checks are performed either by the server or the proxy, and they do not provide a way to query for such items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test on zabbix server side, using the zabbix user you can check by using

```
zabbix_get -s <host> -p <port:10050> -k <key>
```

If the command is not found install it with your package manager, eg: apt install zabbix-get

You can also get the command available on the agent, by launching this command on agent

```
zabbix_agentd -p
```